# How to turn on snap, how to enter global xyz-values for origin points and 3d-cursor and more

Tags: snapping, 3d-cursor, origin

I'm new to Blender but used to work in Softimage and Maya for many years. I have a few questions:

1. Is there a way to turn on snapping, so that when I move my selection it will keep snapping to whatever comes close to what I have selected (fx the grid or vertices on an object)?
2. Can I enter numerical values for global position for origin points and 3d-cursor?
3. Can the 3d-cursor snap to the grid, vertices etc.?
4. Can I adjust things like an objects resolution (fx the number of segments and rings on a sphere) at a later point, or are they lost, once the object is created? Ps. I am familiar with the box that pops up, when an object is created, but it disappears again, and there doesn't seem to be a way to get it back later on.
5. Feature request: It would be nice to be able to enter the number of subdivisions on a plane and a cube upon creation, like you can for fx a sphere. Ps. I am familiar with the 'Loop Cut'-feature.

Comment: Please only ask one question at a time in future. That makes it much easier for subsequent users of this forum to search for answers. I'll just answer your first point below.

Comment: Incidentally there are no Blender developers here so this is not the place to ask for feature requests. The correct place is the [Right-Click Select](https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect) web site.

Answer (score 0):

#### Snapping

Snapping feature is accessible from the top middle menu in the 3D viewport, as shown in the screenshot below.

- the magnet button toggles snapping on an off.
- the drop down button next to it lets you configure snapping behaviour.

[image]

#### Setting position of 3D cursor

This can be done under the `View` tab in 3D viewport.

[image]

#### Snapping the 3D cursor

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> keyboard opens a pie menu with options to snap the 3D cursor.

To snap to an object: Select an object, or a vertex, edge or face in edit mode, then choose `Cursor to selected` in the pie menu.

To snap to the grid: <kbd>Shift</kbd> + Right-click next to the grid point on which you would like to snap the cursor to. This places the 3D cursor next to it. Then in the pie menu, select `Cursor to grid` option.

Comment: Thanks a lot for a quick and very useful answer. That was a big help :-)